# How to add trailing slash with varnish?

Tags: regex, varnish, varnish-vcl

I want to add a trailing slash to all URL's with varnish (via 301 redirect).

I was surprised I couldn't find anything about online anywhere, however.

This was the closest I got, but is obviously broken because it doesn't account for query strings or or anything with a . in it.

```
if (req.url !~ "/$") {
  return (synth (751, ""));
}
```

...

```
sub vcl_synth {
  if (resp.status == 750) {
    set resp.status = 301;
    set resp.http.Location = "http://www.example.com" + req.url;
    return(deliver);
  }
}
```

Test cases I want to account for

`example.com/xyz?query=string` -> `www.example.com/xyz/?query=string` (add www, add /)

`example.com/api/latest.json` -> `www.example.com/api/latest.json` (add www, dont add /)

Comment: look in stack overflow - there is no need for trailing slash for many websites.

Comment: I don't want your opinion, I want an answer to my question.

Comment: So you want to redirect `example.com/xyz?query=string` to `example.com/xyz/?query=string` and `example.com/api/latest.json` to `example.com/api/latest.json/` etc.? Could you please edit your question to give specific examples on how you want the redirect to perform.

Comment: i clarified the 'before and after' example.

Comment: So how can you tell when to add the slash and when not to? If any of your folders contain a dot (xyz.abc), adding the trailing slash doesn't work. This would be much better handled in the backend.

Comment: no paths would ever have a dot in them, that im 100% sure of as I have very strict routing guidelines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution for Varnish 3 that you could translate into Varnish 4. I don't have Varnish 4 handy myself:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.Host !~ "^www\." || (
           req.url !~ {"(?x)
               (?:/$)         # last character isn't a slash
               |              # or
               (?:/\?)        # query string isn't immediately preceded by a slash
           "} &&
           req.url ~ {"(?x)
               (?:/[^./]+$)   # last path segment doesn't contain a . no query string
               |              # or
               (?:/[^.?]+\?)  # last path segment doesn't contain a . with a query string
           "})
    ) {
        error 720;
    }
}

sub vcl_error {
    if (obj.status == 720) {
        set obj.status = 301;

        set obj.http.Location = "http://";
        set obj.http.Host = req.http.Host;
        if (obj.http.Host !~ "^www\.") {
            // for www. prefix
            set obj.http.Host = "www." + obj.http.Host;
        }
        set obj.http.Location = obj.http.Location + obj.http.Host;

        if (req.url ~ "(?:/[^./]+$)|(?:/[^.?]+\?)") {
            // no . in last path segment before optional query string
            if (req.url !~ "/$" && req.url !~ "\?") {
                // no trailing slash and no query string
                set obj.http.Location = obj.http.Location + req.url + "/";
            } else if (req.url ~ "[^/]\?") {
                // no trailing slash and with query string, preserve it
                set obj.http.Location = obj.http.Location +
                  regsub(req.url, "([^?]+)\?.*", "\1") +
                  "/" +
                  regsub(req.url, "[^?]+(\?.*)", "\1");
            } else if (obj.http.Host != req.http.Host) {
                // trailing slash rule met, handle missing www. scenario
                set obj.http.Location = obj.http.Location + req.url;
            }
        } else if (obj.http.Host != req.http.Host) {
            // last path segment contains a . so handle missing www. scenario
            set obj.http.Location = obj.http.Location + req.url;
        }
        set obj.response = "Moved Permanently";
    }
}
```

I have a Varnish test case file that exercises the various URLs you are interested in as well:

```
varnishtest "Testing adding trailing slash"

server s1 {
    rxreq
    txresp -body "hello world"
} -repeat 4 -start

varnish v1 -vcl+backend {
    include "${pwd}/26921577.vcl";
} -start

client c1 {
    txreq -url "/document/" -hdr "Host: www.example.com"
    rxresp

    expect resp.status == 200
    expect resp.body == "hello world"
} -run

client c2 {
    txreq -url "/document" -hdr "Host: www.example.com"
    rxresp

    expect resp.status == 301
    expect resp.http.Location == "http://www.example.com/document/"
} -run

client c3 {
    txreq -url "/document/" -hdr "Host: example.com"
    rxresp

    expect resp.status == 301
    expect resp.http.Location == "http://www.example.com/document/"
} -run

client c4 {
    txreq -url "/document" -hdr "Host: example.com"
    rxresp

    expect resp.status == 301
    expect resp.http.Location == "http://www.example.com/document/"
} -run

client c5 {
    txreq -url "/xyz/?query=string" -hdr "Host: www.example.com"
    rxresp

    expect resp.status == 200
    expect resp.body == "hello world"
} -run

client c6 {
    txreq -url "/xyz?query=string" -hdr "Host: www.example.com"
    rxresp

    expect resp.status == 301
    expect resp.http.Location == "http://www.example.com/xyz/?query=string"
} -run

client c7 {
    txreq -url "/xyz/?query=string" -hdr "Host: example.com"
    rxresp

    expect resp.status == 301
    expect resp.http.Location == "http://www.example.com/xyz/?query=string"
} -run

client c8 {
    txreq -url "/xyz?query=string" -hdr "Host: example.com"
    rxresp

    expect resp.status == 301
    expect resp.http.Location == "http://www.example.com/xyz/?query=string"
} -run

client c9 {
    txreq -url "/api/latest.json" -hdr "Host: www.example.com"
    rxresp

    expect resp.status == 200
    expect resp.body == "hello world"
} -run

client c10 {
    txreq -url "/api/latest.json" -hdr "Host: example.com"
    rxresp

    expect resp.status == 301
    expect resp.http.Location == "http://www.example.com/api/latest.json"
} -run

client c11 {
    txreq -url "/api/latest.json?query=string" -hdr "Host: www.example.com"
    rxresp

    expect resp.status == 200
    expect resp.body == "hello world"
} -run

client c12 {
    txreq -url "/api/latest.json?query=string" -hdr "Host: example.com"
    rxresp

    expect resp.status == 301
    expect resp.http.Location == "http://www.example.com/api/latest.json?query=string"
} -run

varnish v1 -expect client_req == 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on above solution for `varnish 3`, here is the solution for `varnish 4` for handling timeout issues without trailing slash. I was just intrested in appending the trailing slash in varnish request and no other fancy stuff.

Because without trailing slashes I was noticing time out issues espeically on `/wp-admin`. Whereas `/wp-admin/` was working fine. But now after the below updates in `default.vcl` everything works fine.

If you were facing timeout issues and you made the changes and still facing the same issues, do consider flushing cache of your browser, and open the URL in private window of the browser too and try in some other browser that you don't use.

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "(?:/[^./]+$)|(?:/[^.?]+\?)") {
        // no . in last path segment before optional query string

        //add trailing slash to directory URL for instance wp-admin will be replaced with wp-admin/
        if (req.url !~ "/$" && req.url !~ "\?") {
            // no trailing slash and no query string
            set req.url = req.url + "/";
        } else if (req.url ~ "[^/]\?") {
            // no trailing slash and with query string, preserve it
            set req.url = regsub(req.url, "([^?]+)\?.*", "\1") + 
                            "/" + regsub(req.url, "[^?]+(\?.*)", "\1");
        }
    }
}
```

This is working absolutely fine for me, I hope it can help anyone else too.